# Postfix address filtering

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, filter

Is it possible to do sender address filtering within postfix itself? I want to block email where the sender and recipient are both `root@domain.com` except in the case that the email was sent locally.

I would rather not have to install (bloated) anti-spam software just for one filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a [policy server](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html). Standard `smtpd_receipient_restrictions` and `smtpd_sender_restrictions` can't do this exactly - they can do it separately and you could defer from one to the next but it wouldn't be reliable.

Policy server is the best way to go. The page I linked to even shows an example policy server written in Perl.